# mockito spy doesn't work on android studio

Tags: mockito, spy

I'm trying to mock some object and manipulate the return value of the object's method. After applying spy or mock, seems manipulating the return value doesn't work. The final result 'res' is not '10' as I expected but '1'. After instantiating class B and call the method getAAA(), it just calls the real method of A.aaa() and returns '1'.

```
    class A {
        public int aaa() { return 1; }
    }

    class B {
        A classA;

        B(A classA) { this.classA = classA; }

        public int getAAA() { return classA.aaa(); }
    }

    A spyA = mock(A.class);
    when(spyA.aaa()).thenReturn(10);

    A AA = new A();
    int res = new B(AA).getAAA();
    Logxx.d("RESULT: " + res);
```

RESULT: 1

Answer (score 0):

You are not using your mock/ spy instead you are creating new object with new.
Also, you are mocking the object with `mock(...)` but you are calling you object as spy(spyA). This isn't wrong since it is just a variable name. But not readable.

```
    A mockA = mock(A.class);
    when(spyA.aaa()).thenReturn(10);

    A AA = new A();
    int res = new B(mockA).getAAA();
    Logxx.d("RESULT: " + res);
```